# Covert a list of dict objects to json but without brakets

Tags: python-3.x

I am not a developer myself so it could be a dump question.. So I need to convert a list of dict to a json file. my list looks like

```
[{'cpu0': 0.6}, {'cpu1': 0.8}]
```

I need it to become

```
{'fields': {'cpu0': 0.6, 'cpu1': 0.8}}
```

I tried with `json.dumps(my_list)` and it would have these brackets and braces in it so it becomes

```
{'fields': '[{"cpu0": 0.6}, {"cpu1": 0.8}]'}
```

The list could have more items than just two (cpu0 and cpu1) in this example...

Any advice on how to do it? Thanks and happy Friday!!

Comment: Can you show the code you used to create that json from `my_list`? Because `json.dumps(my_list)` would give you `[{'cpu0': 0.6}, {'cpu1': 0.8}]`, not `{'fields': '[{"cpu0": 0.6}, {"cpu1": 0.8}]'}`

Comment: Your result *is not JSON*. It's not clear what JSON has to do with your question. `json.dumps(my_list)` would result in `'[{"cpu0": 0.6}, {"cpu1": 0.8}]'` which *is valid JSON*. JSON is a. text-based serialization format... so of course, it produces a `str` object, but it seems like you just want a `dict` object

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thanks for the response. The `fields` is an arbitrary field required in the resulted json file in order to be written in the DB

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for the response. I should make my original list a dict object like `{'cpu0': 0.6, 'cpu1': 0.8}` to begin with to avoid this conversion... But I have to get the json file because it is the required format by the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the json to be a dict with one key -- `'fields'`, whose value is itself a dict with two keys -- `'cpu0'` and `'cpu1'`

However, it looks like you created a dictionary with one key: `'fields'`, and then set its value to `json.dumps(my_list)`.

Instead, you should actually create the object you want, and *then* convert to json:

```
flds = dict()       # Create a flds dictionary to collect all the key-value pairs from my_list
for d in my_list:   # Iterate over each of the dictionaries in my_list
    flds.update(d)  # Update flds with all key-value pairs in this dictionary

my_dict = {'fields': flds}  # Create the output object
json_str = json.dumps(my_dict) # Dump it to json

print(json_str)
```

Which outputs:

```
{"fields": {"cpu0": 0.6, "cpu1": 0.8}}
```

Comment: This code works great! thanks!